# Джанго. Пагинация и нумерация

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, шаблоны

Всем вечерочка. Суть в следующем: страница формирует список объектов `tasks` по номеру page. Я получаю номер отдельной задачи (`num`) так:  `start_index_on_curr_page` из шаблон 'content.html' (см. рис) + номер итерации.  `num` передается дальше в шаблон отдельной задачи. Однако операция сложения здесь не определена. Где нужно подсчитывать `num` в таком случае?

**content.html:**

```
   <ul class="list-tasks">
        {% for task in tasks %}
            {% include 'mainapp/task_block.html' with task=task num=start_index_on_curr_page+forloop.counter %}
        {%endfor%}
    </ul>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#add

```
   <ul class="list-tasks">
        {% for task in tasks %}
            {% include 'mainapp/task_block.html' with task=task num=start_index_on_curr_page|add:forloop.counter %}
        {%endfor%}
    </ul>
```

Comment: помогло, спасибо_)